# Mongoose populate return undefined when asking one property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to develop something using NodeJS and Mongoose. I have a collection of "Pokemon" objects, and for some of them I have a DBRef to another "Pokemon" object from the same collection.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PokemonSchema = new Schema({
  id: {type: Number, min: 1, index: {unique: true}},
  name: {type: String, index: {unique: true}},
  local_name: {type: String, index: {unique: true}},
  _evolution_candy: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Pokemon" }
});
```

However, when I try to get the information contained in my DBRef, I get "undefined" incessantly. Yet when I make a console log of my parent object I see the reference:

```
  Pokemon
    .findOne({
      $or: [
        {"name": alias},
        {"local_name": alias},
        {"id": parseInt(alias) || 0}
      ]
    })
    .populate("_evolution_candy")
    .exec(function(err, pokemon) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      if (null === pokemon) return message.channel.send(
        "Il n'y a aucune entrée dans le Pokédex pour le nom ou l'identifiant `" + alias + "`."
      );

      console.log(pokemon);    
      console.log(pokemon._evolution_candy);
    })
  ;
```

Here the output:

```
{ _id: 59f8f6b1142e4035a08666e9,
  id: 64,
  name: 'kadabra',
  local_name: 'kadabra',
  evolution_candy:
   DBRef {
     _bsontype: 'DBRef',
     namespace: 'pokemons',
     oid: 59cfbe4afa002f766c679138,
     db: 'pr_willow' } }
undefined
```

I specify that the DBRef is good, directly created with a Mongo client.
Where could I have made a mistake?

Comment: Mongoose is not expecting a `DBRef`. It;s just expecting an `ObjectId` which is the same as the `_id` value in the related collection. It's the job of the "schema" to define where that is, just like you did in defining the schema. You don't want `DBRef`, which is as close to officially deprecated as it gets ( still unsure why that has not yet happened ).

Comment: Ok thx @NeilLunn. Coming from Doctrine Mongodb, I stayed on the DBRef. I did not know it was depreciated in passing. Thank you !

Comment: `DBRef` has always been a bad idea. Even `.populate()` is old hat. Modern MongoDB releases support [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which actually joins on the "server". All these other things are just "emulations of a join" which actually just perform other queries to the database when you are not looking ( well they actually just chain another query, point is you're not doing that manually ).